# How to check and choose which compiler is used in Xcode6?

Tags: ios, xcode6

Sorry for the extremely stupid question, but I can't find the solution anywhere on the Internet.

---

**Remember:**

Choose "All" instead of "Basic" (at the top-left corner) when searching, like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Nah, it is not stupid. I didn't know either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project setting and search for `compiler`. You will see it like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check the compiler used in Xcode by following steps:-
1)Go to Project Target
2)Select Build Setting & search for compiler u will get the compiler name.

Answer (score 1):

From Xcode:

- Click on your project
- Choose a target (it may be choose by default)
- Click on Build Settings tab
- Search "Build Options" and check "Compiler for C/C++/Objective -C"
  if there are multiple compiler then you can change it.